# Why is first sound slow to play with soundmanager2?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just finished this jquery plugin to display musical scales:

[www.daveconservatoire.org/tools/scales](http://www.daveconservatoire.org/tools/scales)

The piano keys are clickable and play the relevant notes.  I'm using the Soundmanager2 package.

I'm loading all the sounds when the page loads, but even when loaded I notice that the first note I click takes a while to playback the note - but then when I click on either that note or any other note the playback is quick and crisp.

Why does it take a second or so to "wake up" soundmanager?

Comment: Sadly not, I still have the same problem!